# Manifest for Windows XP SP3?

Tags: c++, xml, windows, manifest, exe

I'm looking for a manifest file for themida to make the executable file open as admin and in Windows XP SP3 compatibility modus. Could not find this Manifest nowhere, anybody some idea?

Comment: This is absolutely on topic

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify compatibility mode in a manifest. That's done through the registry. Some useful resources that describe this further:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756937.aspx
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/10/05/the-program-compatibility-assistant-part-two.aspx
- https://superuser.com/questions/379375/how-can-i-set-the-compatibility-mode-for-an-executable-from-the-command-line
- http://www.verboon.info/index.php/2011/03/running-an-application-as-administrator-or-in-compatibility-mode/